# Breakpoint is not working in one form, but is properly working in another form in C#

Tags: c#

```
 private void btnprintdealer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
 {     //HERE I GIVE BREAKPOINT.  BUT,IT IS NOT PROPERLY WORKING.
            print();

    }
    public void print()
    {


        pdoc.OriginAtMargins = false;
        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;

        pd.Document = pdoc;
        pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;

        pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);

        DialogResult result = pd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            PrintPreviewDialog pp = new PrintPreviewDialog();

            pp.Document = pdoc;

            pp.ShowDialog();
            result = pp.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hai");
                pdoc.Print();
            }
        }



    }
  public  void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {



        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

        RectangleF marginBounds = e.MarginBounds;
        RectangleF printableArea = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;

        //Rectangle 1
        graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, 20, 810, 540);



    }
```

Breakpoint is not working in one form. But it is properly working in another form in my project in C#.

Comment: What do you mean by not properly working??

Comment: Do you have a button which invokes the btnprintdealer_Click() method in the form that is not working?

Comment: Make sure you have attached your Button_Click event to `btnprintdealer_Click`

Comment: Are you sure the code at breakpoint is reached at all?

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure that you have not wiredup `Click` Event handler properly for your button `btnprintdealer`

Try This:

```
btnprintdealer.Click +=btnprintdealer_Click;
```

Comment: But,I don't know where it to be initialized?

Comment: @SyedMohamesYasinM: initialise it in the Form_Load Event handler.